# Glide - ImageView height is 0dp for first load

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I send images to server via Retrofit. When sending process is completed my FeedFragment is opening and last sent image must be shown at the top of RecyclerView (first position). But imageView is invisible at first load. Only if I scroll down and scroll up it's becoming visible. Glide Code (in RecyclerView Adapter):

```
                           Glide.with(context)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(ApiClient.Base_URL + imagesList.get(0).getImage())
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                            .dontAnimate()
                            .dontTransform()
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    //for dynamic image height:
                                    targetImageHeight = (resource.getHeight() * deviceHeight) / resource.getWidth();

                                    if (targetImageHeight >= deviceHeight) {
                                        targetImageHeight = deviceHeight;
                                    }
                                    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = targetImageHeight;
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                                    Glide.with(context).clear(imageView);
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });
```

xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is that view is not drawn yet. Correct approach would be using view.post() method that would execute provided runnable only after view has completed drawing

Comment: @Heisenberg I couldn't understand exactly. Could you give an example(code) Mr White ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

```
void load(final ImageView imageView) {
if (imageView.getHeight() == 0) {
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            load(imageView);
            return true; // == allow drawing
        }
    });
} else {
    Glide
            .with(imageView.getContext())
            .load("whatever")
            .fitCenter()
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, imageView.getHeight())
            .into(imageView);
   }
 }
```